# Node.js determine path targeted by symlink

Tags: node.js, symlink-traversal

Note: using Node.js 8

I have a series of symlinks: `a` -> `b` -> `c`

I need to resolve the initial symlink `a` to its target destination `b`.  How can this be accomplished in Node.js?

The `fs.realpath` function resolves chains of symlinks, so it resolves `a` to `c`.  This is not the desired behavior.

I've also attempted to find an `npm` package to do this, but haven't had any luck so far.

I thought maybe I could `fs.open` the symlink and read the contents, but I could not figure out how to access the documented `fs.constants.O_SYMLINK` constant, probably because I'm on Node 8.

Comment: [Node 8](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/fs.html#fs_file_open_constants) documentation also lists `fs.constants.O_SYMLINK`. What is there to figure out? If you type that into the REPL, doesn't it give you a numeric value?

Comment: No, `fs.constants.O_SYMLINK` is undefined.

Comment: What does `node -v` output?

Comment: `node -v` outputs `v8.10.0`

Answer (score 14):

I searched Node.js documentation for the word "symlink", but the Node documentation just refers to these as a "link".  The solution is to use [`fs.readlink()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readlink_path_options_callback):

```
const {readlink} = require("fs");

fs.readlink("a", (err, target) => {
    if (!err) console.log(target);    // prints "b"
});
```